# How to get a rails app load path? (in order to configure rsense for a certain rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, emacs, autocomplete

Is there any command that I can run on rails console in order to get the load-path for a certain app?

I would like to have this in order to put the load-path in my .rsense file so I can have emacs auto-completition and jump-to-definition for my app classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
irb(main):011:0> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
=> ["/home/mike/projects/myapp/vendor/gems", ...
```

I think for rails 2 it was the just called load_paths instead of autoload_paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Rails.root** or **RAILS_ROOT** (older one).